# CakePHP high production time

Tags: database, performance, cakephp, background-process, production

when I use just a controller and a view to display some links (no database access) it takes about 50ms to load the page, but when it comes to database access (my model uses a database here) it takes about 1.1s ALTHOUGH I am only using the find-command with the limitation of 10 entries. The sql command is being executed pretty fast (~ 0ms - 1ms) but it seems there are other processes being done in the background.

Here is the code:

```
public function index() {
$this->set('allLeser', $this->Leser->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('id', 'vorname', 'nachname', 'klassenstufe', 'klassenbezeichner'),
    'limit' => 10
)));
$this->set('title', 'Leser');
}
```

I would like to know, why it takes so long to produce the page

**EDIT: I found the solution: the persistent flag in my database configuration was set to false. I changed it to true and my page production time was lowered to 45ms - 60ms. Why is this flag set to false by default... ._.**

Comment: How big is the returned array? If you add `debug( $allLeser )` to the view you should see the whole thing. It might pull a lot of data from the associated models.

Comment: Try to set recursive to -1 before executing the find command. `$this->Leser->recursive = -1;`

Comment: The returned array is 10 entries big. Thus my limitation worked. To me it seems like my model loads all the data automatically, which costs a lot of performance, as my table is about 1500 items big.

Setting recursive to -1 didnt change the load time either.

Comment: Is your table indexed correctly?

Comment: And, try turning debug to zero `0` - when debug is on there are a LOT of things happening including updating all table schemas...etc.  (you can see what it does when debug is on by using DebugKit)

Comment: Yes, my table is indexed correctly. My auto-incrementing, index row's name is 'id'. I start to despair, becuase this is so weird, as I am only displaying a few entries. Are there other suggestions, you could give me? Should I try creating a new table with less entries and then displaying them on another page? Setting debug to `0` didn't change the page production time.

Comment: Look at the Timer tab in DebugKit to see where the time is being taken.

Comment: The most time took my controller, as he was waiting for the database connection being established.